# Rolling 5 dice in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dice

I was given:

```
    def rollDice(dice, toRoll=[0,1,2,3,4]):

        """Rolls specified dice. If no dice are specified, all dice are rolled."""
        for i in toRoll:
            dice[i] = random.randint(1,6)
```

For the life of me I cannot figure out how to call this function to roll five dice. I've tried rollDice(5,toRoll) and some other variations. Also i do have a return line elsewhere

Comment: What is the toRoll var ? I see what is doing but why a list? And not an int, so you just for i in range(0, toRoll):

Comment: Did you write that function? What's your actual goal? I don't understand what dice is supposed to be. I presume `toRoll` is the number of times you'd like to roll, but why would you make that a list?

Comment: What is a typical output when you roll 5 dice? What should the function actually return?

Comment: No i did not write the function, I was given it  in and assignment and told to roll 5 dice then display the standard output. I assume it should return a list of numbers that the dice landed on . Any assistance with how to actually call the function?

Comment: look up how to call a function

Comment: This function is terrible.

Comment: Mutable defaults are terrible.

Answer (score 2):

Being an assignment question, I want to give you a hint:

Think about how dice is used in the function:

- A value is assigned to it inside the `for loop`
- It is something that is "indexed" using an integer `i`

Use [this page](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html) as a reference to see if you can get hints

Comment: No offense but I've been trying a lot including reading around,  if i could figure it out on my own I wouldn't post here.

Comment: None taken, I did try to add hints but looks like that didn't help. I was trying to allude you to explore lists and dicts as possible data structures for dice. Anyway, I didn't want to answer it for you :)

Answer (score 1):

That function writes to its first argument.  Try this:

```
dice = [None] * 5
rollDice(dice)
print(dice)
```

Comment: I got none as the reply

Comment: @user6184617: try now.